# Syntax highlighting rules and definitions

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting

Are there any standard syntax highlighting rules for R? If yes, where can they be found?

Or does each editor, IDE, package (e.g., the highlight package) create their own rule set?

Comment: +1 have thought about this too, but never had the courage to ask on SO :)

Comment: +1 and it would be nice to surface your [tag:rstudio] example from [**chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12961957#12961957)

Comment: Not that I know of. I searched around a bit, while putting together my tk script editor package [rite](https://github.com/leeper/rite), and didn't find anything...I basically tried to copy the apparent formatting rules provided by Notepad++ (without complete success).

Comment: @SimonO101 I just found that there is an r_highlight.html file in my RStudio installation that apparently defines the highlighting with java script and some regex.

Comment: ACE code editor has a syntax mode file for R that you can reference.  https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/mode-r.js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each editor creates their own rule set.  For historical reasons, each editor has implemented syntax highlighting in its own way.  Having a cross-editor standard may be possible using, for example, [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/), but it would almost certainly require a lot of effort getting editor makers to sign up to it, especially if they already have their own system.

Eclipse uses `.hrc` files for storing syntax information.
RStudio has a file called [r_highlight.html](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/master/src/cpp/session/resources/r_highlight.html).
Notepad++ stores keywords for different languages in a file named `langs.model.xml`.
Textpad has its own [`.syn` format](http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/synn2t.html) for the code highlighting.
TextWrangler has [a plugin](https://files.nyu.edu/jmb736/public/code/R_language_module_for_BBEdit/R.plist).

Comment: There's a plugin for TextWrangler, for you OSX users.  https://files.nyu.edu/jmb736/public/code/R_language_module_for_BBEdit/R.plist  Oh, and SciTe has an R ruleset, too.

Comment: There's also the highlight package if you want to do it from R code