# Syntax Highlighting in R default editor

Tags: r

Is there any way to display the code syntax colored in R? I don't wish to use RStudio, TinnR etc. to accomplish the same. Please specify.

I have [connected it to sublime](http://tomschenkjr.net/blog/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/) and used it editor which is pretty good, but I am looking for some simplistic approach.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999687/syntax-highlighting-rules-and-definitions) somewhat comes close what I am asking. But I guess mine pretty simple.

It seems weird it wouldn't be possible to accomplish something already which should implicit.

Right now(No syntax color):

```
 write.csv2(dfwith, file = "writecsv2.csv")
```

Required(With Syntax Color):

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;"><div class="geshifilter"><pre class="r geshifilter-R" style="font-family:monospace;"> <a href="http://inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/write.csv2"><span style="color: #003399; font-weight: bold;">write.csv2</span></a><span style="color: #009900;">&#40;</span>dfwith<span style="color: #339933;">,</span> <a href="http://inside-r.org/r-doc/base/file"><span style="color: #003399; font-weight: bold;">file</span></a> = <span style="color: #0000ff;">&quot;writecsv2.csv&quot;</span><span style="color: #009900;">&#41;</span></pre></div></div><p><a href="http://www.inside-r.org/pretty-r" title="Created by Pretty R at inside-R.org">Created by Pretty R at inside-R.org</a></p>
```

Comment: This could be a programming question, one use could options and change editor, which tried before but didn't work. I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: There are no downvotes. But the question is pretty unclear – I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Check now.

Comment: No, that doesn’t help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to accomplish, as your question is pretty ambiguous, but hopefully this could be of some help.

As an alternative to Sublime, you can use Notepad++ as R's "built-in" editor.  By this I mean that you would create/edit functions and scripts in Notepad++:

[image: The result of fixing a function]

(This screenshot is how it looks on my dual monitors)

Typing `fix(some_func)` or `some_func <- edit(some_func)` would both open in Notepad++.

If this seems like something you're looking for, it can be done by going to `‘R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site’`, where `R_HOME` is the directory it's installed.  After locating the `Rprofile.site` file, open it in Notepad++ and change the following:

```
# options(papersize="a4")
options(editor="notepad")
# options(pager="internal")
```

to:

```
# options(papersize="a4")
options(editor="C://Program Files (x86)//Notepad++//notepad++.exe")
# options(pager="internal")
```

Save the file and you're done.

Comment: This is not working for me, any idea wh that might be?

Comment: What in particular is not working?  Opening in Notepad++, the syntax coloring, or something else?

Comment: After making the changes you suggested, notepad++ is not used as the default edior (it still just opens in R editor)